# What is the difference between java.lang.reflect and the maven org.reflections?

Tags: java, maven, reflection, pom.xml

I am starting with reflections in java. Looking through an external project, I saw that the developer hast used the dependency `org-reflections` in his pom.xml instead of the already included java `java.lang.reflect` class.
Does this maven dependency provide further methods?

Comment: I would not bother with [Reflections Library](https://www.baeldung.com/reflections-library) for now if you just start with reflections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**java.lang.reflect** : It's a package where reflection API classes are present. It can help you examine or modify the behavior of methods, classes, interfaces at runtime.

**org-reflections** It's an external library which makes developer's life easier, as using reflection code API was/is very a cumbersome activity (at least before the introduction of `VarHandle and MethodHandle`) . I recommend you to go through the readme file here:
https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections they have nicely explained some of the features with examples.

e.g. suppose you want to list all the classes annotated with `@RestController`

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.demo");

Set<Class<?>> controllerCls = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(RestController.class);
```

Now try writing the same code without using `Reflections` API